# Generating Redux Toolkit TypeScript types when using preloadedState

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to set up my test environment that includes React Testing Library, Redux Toolkit, RTK Query and TypeScript but I've run into a problem I can't resolve.

The main issue I can't figure out is how to generate the `AppDispatch` type [as explained in the documentation here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type) when supplying a `preloadedState`.

Going by the RTK docs and using `configureStore()` directly is no problem, as the store is being created inside the module:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    home: homeReducer,
    [homeApi.reducerPath]: homeApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
    homeApi.middleware,
  ),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.reducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch; // not a problem as store exists here

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

export default store;
```

However, doing it this way makes it difficult to pass a `preloadedState` value to `configureStore()` and keep the generated types. If I extract the reducer and use `combineReducers()` I can generate `RootState` from there, but I still can't figure out how to export `AppDispatch` as `store.dispatch` doesn't exist until the store is created, and in order to pass `preloadedState` I need to delay the creation of the store.

```
export const rootInitialState: Pick<RootState, 'home'> = {
  home: homeInitialState,
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
  home: homeReducer,
  [homeApi.reducerPath]: homeApi.reducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;

// this is the problem as store is created externally to this module,
// so how can I extract this type now?
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch; 

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

export const createStore = (preloadedState: Partial<RootState>) => configureStore({
  reducer,
  preloadedState,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
    homeApi.middleware,
  ),
});
```

Can this actually be done? At this point I'm totally stumped so if anyone can either offer a solution or put me out of my misery, I'd be hugely appreciative either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's straightforward, you just need to change the ordering of the declarations in the file and add one more level of inspection.

The key is that while we don't have a real store yet, we do have `createStore`, which returns the new store instance. TS can figure out "the type of the value returned by this function", so we can use that instead:

```
export const createStore = (preloadedState: Partial<RootState>) => configureStore({
  reducer,
  preloadedState,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
    homeApi.middleware,
  ),
});

// 1) Take the type of `createStore`
// 2) Figure out the return type of that function, which is a store
// 3) Look up the type of the `dispatch` field in that returned store type
export type AppDispatch = ReturnType<typeof createStore>['dispatch'];
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much that's exactly what I've been looking for!